# Angular reactive form - invalidate disabled element

Tags: angular

It looks like when an element is disabled it's not a part of a form validation.
I have the following code:
html:

```
        <button
            mat-flat-button
            [disabled]="formGroup.controls['assetName'].invalid">
        </button>
```

ts:

```
assetName: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, {validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur'}],
```

I run the form when asset name is initially blank. But the button is enabled. If I declare asset name with disabled: false then the button is disabled.
My question is how to invalidate a disabled element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the states of a FormControl are VALID, INVALID, PENDING and DISABLED
see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlStatus)

You need use `!valid`

```
[disabled]="!formGroup.controls['assetName'].valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a validator.

```
function checkDisabledControlValidity(controlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    if (control.disabled && !control.value) {
      return { requiredWhenDisabled: true };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

attache it to the group

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  assetName: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur' }]
}, { validators: checkDisabledControlValidity('assetName') });
```

your button

```
<button mat-flat-button [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">
  Submit
</button>
```